# How can I change div contents using jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I have some code that allows the user to click on an icon to save that item to their favorites or remove from favorites. I want to change the icon using jquery/AJAX. I am wondering how to return the code from the PHP file to update the page without reloading. 
Essentially I would like to update the color of the heart icon and add or remove the word 'Save'.

Here is my AJAX code for displaying the div:

```
function deleteLink( deleteID ){

var deletedID = deleteID;

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "deleteLink.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data:  { 'deletedID' : deletedID },

    success: function(deleteIDFunc){
        var deleteIDFunc = $.trim(deleteIDFunc);
        if(deleteIDFunc){               
            $('#removeSaved').html(deleteIDFunc); //<-how can I change the div so that it will display the other icon
        }
        else {
            alert('Your saved post was not removed. Please try again');
        }
    }
});
}
```

Here is my Database code for deleting and updating the database: this updates and works properly.

```
function check_input($dirtData) {
  $dirtData = trim($dirtData);
  $dirtData = strip_tags($dirtData);
  $dirtData = stripslashes($dirtData);
  $dirtData = htmlspecialchars($dirtData);
  $dirtData = filter_var($dirtData, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  return $dirtData;
}

if(isset($_POST['id'])){

$ID = check_input($_SESSION['user_session']);
$link_id = check_input($_POST['id']);

$query = "INSERT INTO savelink (saveUser_id, link_id) VALUES ($ID, $link_id)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$returnID = "ok";
echo $returnID;
}else{
    return false;
}

if(isset($_POST['deletedID'])){

$id = check_input($_POST['deletedID']);

$query = "DELETE FROM savelink WHERE saveLink_id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$deleteIDFunc = '';  //<-do I need to put some html code here and then return json for changing the div
echo json_encode($deleteIDFunc);
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Lastly here is the code where the item is displayed:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']) && $row['saveUser_id'] == $_SESSION['user_session']){
    $returnNew .= '<span id="removeSaved"><a href="javascript:void();" class="pull-right" onclick="deleteLink('.$row['saveLink_id'].');"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:#d52917;"></i></a></span>';
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])){
    $returnNew .= '<span id="showSaved"><a href="javascript:void();" class="pull-right" onclick="saveLink('.$row['topic_id'].');">Save <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></span>';
}
```

Comment: In your PHP code you should return if it's added or removed to favourites in your JS code you should just check what php code return and change color with css class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MorganFreeFarm, I am actually looking to change the div and add or remove the word 'save' as well as the color. I updated my question.

Comment: You can set id to your anchor and use `$("#saveButton").text('NEW TEXT');` Where `NEW TEXT` is your text and you can change it on every click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple,

you can add after the following content in "showSaved" to the "removeSaved" div and make "removeSaved div hide.

eg as follows :-

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "deleteLink.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data:  { 'deletedID' : deletedID },

    success: function(deleteIDFunc){
        var deleteIDFunc = $.trim(deleteIDFunc);
        if(deleteIDFunc){               
            $('#removeSaved').html(deleteIDFunc); //<-how can I change the div so that it will display the other icon
            $('#removeSaved').hide();
            $("#removeSaved").after('<span id="showSaved"><a href="javascript:void();" class="pull-right" onclick="saveLink('+deletedID +');">Save <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></span>');

        }
        else {
            alert('Your saved post was not removed. Please try again');
        }
    }
});
```

Please note the ID to pass, if you want pass the id to the ajax function deleteLink()

Comment: Perfect, that is what was needed. Thanks @Farveen Hassan